# Combine Data from Multiple Rows in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am using Pandas as part of Python and I have the following table. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do the following. Any help would be much appreciated.

I have a data table where there are many duplicate timepoints. However each duplicate timepoint has a different portion of the row filled in. I want to combine all the timepoints into a single row that contains all the information.

I do not want to sum the columns.
I do not want to concatenate the columns.

I want to take the first value of a single timepoint in a certain column and ignore any additional values in that column for the same timepoint.

The table should make this much more clear.

```
+----------------+---+---+---+--+---+---+---+--+---+---+---+
| 09/07/20171310 |   | 1 |   |  |   |   |   |  |   |   |   |
| 09/07/20171310 |   |   | 1 |  |   |   |   |  |   |   |   |
| 09/07/20171310 | 3 |   |   |  |   |   |   |  |   |   |   |
| 09/07/20171310 |   |   |   |  |   |   |   |  |   |   | 1 |
| 09/07/20171310 |   |   |   |  |   |   | 1 |  |   |   |   |
| 09/07/20171310 |   |   |   |  |   |   |   |  | 2 |   |   |
| 09/07/20171310 |   |   |   |  | 2 |   |   |  |   |   |   |
| 09/07/20171920 |   |   |   |  |   |   |   |  |   | 1 |   |
| 09/07/20171920 |   |   |   |  |   |   |   |  |   |   | 1 |
| 09/07/20171920 |   |   |   |  |   |   | 1 |  |   |   |   |
| 09/07/20171920 |   |   |   |  |   | 1 |   |  |   |   |   |
| 09/07/20171920 |   |   |   |  |   |   |   |  | 3 |   |   |
| 09/07/20171920 |   |   |   |  | 3 |   |   |  |   |   |   |
| 09/07/20171920 | 6 |   |   |  |   |   |   |  |   |   |   |
| 09/07/20171920 |   |   | 1 |  |   |   |   |  |   |   |   |
| 09/07/20171920 |   | 4 |   |  |   |   |   |  |   |   |   |
+----------------+---+---+---+--+---+---+---+--+---+---+---+
```

I would like to have

```
+----------------+---+---+---+--+---+---+---+--+---+---+---+
| 09/07/20171310 | 3 | 1 | 1 |  | 2 |   | 1 |  | 2 |   | 1 |
| 09/07/20171920 | 6 | 4 | 1 |  | 3 | 1 | 1 |  | 3 | 1 | 1 |
+----------------+---+---+---+--+---+---+---+--+---+---+---+
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the timestamp is the index, use `groupby` + `max`:

```
df.groupby(level=0).max().fillna('')

+----------------+---+---+---+--+---+-----+---+--+---+-----+---+
| 09/07/20171310 | 3 | 1 | 1 |  | 2 |     | 1 |  | 2 |     | 1 |
| 09/07/20171920 | 6 | 4 | 1 |  | 3 | 1.0 | 1 |  | 3 | 1.0 | 1 |
+----------------+---+---+---+--+---+-----+---+--+---+-----+---+
```

If not the index, change `level=0` to `df.columns[0]` instead.

Another assumption here is that your empty values are `NaN`s. If not, replace them *before* grouping:

```
df = df.replace('^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
```

Comment: thanks it worked beautifully. Im new to this site so please let me know if there is something I can do to indicate your answer was good

Comment: @NimayKulkarni You've accepted my answer, so that's mighty plenty. Once you reach 15 rep, you can also upvote answers if you felt they were helpful. Happy coding.